# Why Rstudio vs JRI engine outputs are different?

Tags: java, r, jri

JAVA CODE

```
rengine.eval("x <- ts(1:10, frequency = 4, start = c(1959, 2))");
System.out.println(rengine.eval("x"));
```

JAVA CONSOLE

```
[INT* (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)]
```

R CODE

```
x <- ts(1:10, frequency = 4, start = c(1959, 2))
x
```

R CONSOLE

```
Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4

1959         1    2    3

1960    4    5    6    7

1961    8    9   10
```

I have no experiences with R language.I try to understand what is wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The R output is due to the `print` method used. Java seems to use its own printing and gives you the underlying data structure (similar to `print.default(ts(1:10, frequency = 4, start = c(1959, 2)))` in R).

Comment: My main purpose i,s run  R code in Java Codes.But outputs are different and R has many functions  boxCox.lamda ,auto.arima,forecast  after ts function .How can I sure result are equal? I cant  compare results.

Comment: The results are not different, they are only printed differently. I don't know Java and can't help with using R's print methods in Java.

Comment: I got it ,thank you Roland .